# Extract embedded resource without WebResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, webresource.axd

Are there any ways to programmatically extract an embedded resource instead of going through the WebResource.axd handler?  I have the two parameters (d & t) that are passed to the WebResource.axd handler.  I'm hoping there's a way I can use those parameters to extract the resource myself.  Any tips are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Assembly class. The code below returns an embedded resource as a stream from the current assembly:

```
using System.Reflection;

Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YourEmbeddedResource");
```

Comment: Thanks, but two issues.  (1) The resource is in most cases going to be one of the ASP.NET scripts where JS functions like WebForm_PostBackOptions() are defined.  Do you know which assembly that would be in?  (2) I don't have the embedded resource name, just the "d" and "t" values, which are rather cryptic values that I believe are different than the embedded resource name.

Comment: Those scripts are in the System.Web.dll assembly. You can use Reflector to find their names.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good article about decrypting those "d" and "t" parameters, [Debugging ASP.NET 2.0 Web Resources: Decrypting the URL and Getting the Resource Name](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/07-03-26/debugging_asp_net_2_0_web_resources_decrypting_the_url_and_getting_the_resource_name.aspx). Note that the t parameter is a timestamp, the d parameter contains the resource name that is requested.

Comment: Link is dead.  http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/07-03-26/debugging_asp_net_2_0_web_resources_decrypting_the_url_and_getting_the_resource_name.aspx is currently working.